# How do I access an Apache web server using a domian name instead of IP?

Tags: apache2, ip

I am runnning an Apache server and I want to access my site by typing `something.somethingelse.gr` instead of 192.168.1.105 .

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder and copy the default `00-default.conf` file to `mysite.conf`.  You can use any unique name for the `mysite.conf`.  In this case you could call it `something-somethingelse-gr.conf` (for your own personal identifying your designation for this virtual site.

Then edit your new configuration.  Uncomment the `ServerName` directive and replace the `www.example.com` with `something.somethingelse.gr`.  You can also add other names to call the same server by using the `ServerAlias` directive as described below.

Change from:

```
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
#ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Change to:

```
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerName something.somethingelse.gr
    ServerAlias www.something.somethingelse.gr

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Then run this from the commandline:

```
$ a2ensite mysite.conf
```

Comment: This leaves out DNS system which would be absolutely necessary if not using avahi or similar as suggested by @user98651

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an Avahi Daemon will map a "mymachine.local" into a local ip address if that is what you mean.

However you would need to provide more details as to your needs if you want more specific advice.

eg. Is this over a local network? Is it to be accessed from the internet. what top-level domain (.com .ag .ie) do you want/need?

Comment: Please don't use the `Answers` part of the `Stack Exchange` format for `Questions`.  If you have `Questions` use the `add a comment` for your questions.  `Stack Exchange` has a strict format where `Questions` are for `Questions` not answers.  `Answers` are for `Answers`, not questions.  `Comments` are opened for asking questions for clarifications, as well as giving suggestions to test, which might or might not work, so that you can get feedback on the results.  Look at [help] for more details on how to use `Stack Exchange` and the `Askubuntu.com` part of it.